# How do I pass an array to a custom Django database function?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a Django wrapper for PostgreSQL's `width_bucket` like this:

```
from django.db.models import Func
from django.db import models
class Log2Bucket(Func):
    template = "width_bucket(%(expressions)s::double precision[])"

    def __init__(self, expression, a, b, **extra):
        buckets = []
        while a <= b:
            buckets.append(str(a))
            a *= 2
        buckets = Value(buckets, output_field=ArrayField(models.FloatField()))
        super().__init__(expression, buckets,
            output_field=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), **extra)
```

This works for queries like

```
Foo.objects.annotate(b=Log2Bucket('bar', 125, 100000)).values('b')
```

But for

```
from django.db.models import Count
(Foo.objects.annotate(b=Log2Bucket('bar', 125, 100000))
    .values('b').annotate(count=Count('pk')))
```

I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` from inside Django.

If I use

```
buckets = Value(tuple(buckets), output_field= ...
```

I still get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` from the same place.

How do I fix this? Is there an approach that makes this function less hacky?

<del>I've tried using `function = 'width_bucket'` instead of `template = ...`, but then I get a PostgreSQL error `function width_bucket(double precision, numeric[]) does not exist`.</del> I upgraded to PostgreSQL 10 and this went away.

Comment: Try tuple instead of list

Comment: Sorry, that also didn't work.

Comment: You got 2 buckets "Value(buckets,...)" and "super().__init__(expression, buckets,"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around it like this:

```
class Log2Bucket(Func):
function = 'width_bucket'

    def __init__(self, expression, a, b, **extra):
        buckets = []
        while a <= b:
            buckets.append(str(a))
            a *= 2
        buckets = Value("{%s}" % ','.join(map(str, buckets)))
        super().__init__(expression, buckets,
            output_field=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), **extra)
```

which works, but isn't pretty.